# std::string - get data from start to end

Tags: c++, stdstring

I want to get some data between some 2 indexes.
For example, I have string: "just testing..." and I need string from 2 till 6. I should get:
'st tes'.

What function can do this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `substr`:

```
std::string myString = "just testing...";

std::string theSubstring = myString.substr(2, 6);
```

Note that the second parameter is the *length* of the substring, not an index (your question is a bit unclear, since the substring from 2 to 6 is actually 'st t', not 'st tes').

Answer (score 1):

use the [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) method:

```
std::string theString = "just testing";
std::string theSubstring = theString.substr(2, 4);
```